# JavaScript - Can't assign variable

Tags: javascript, variables, variable-assignment

My simple code is :

```
var child1 = document.getElementsByClassName("item1")[0].innerHTML;
var child2 = document.getElementsByClassName("item2")[0].innerHTML;
var child3 = document.getElementsByClassName("item3")[0].innerHTML;
var child4 = document.getElementsByClassName("item4")[0].innerHTML;
var arr = [child1, child2, child3, child4];
```

But when I run the document in Firefox, then open the console and type `child1`, or type `arr`, I get `undefined` in the console.

When I type, say, `document.getElementsByClassName("item1")[0].innerHTML;`, I get the right content in the console, like so :

```
"<div class="inh">♠</div>"
```

This is actually my content, but I can't assign it to variable !! any help would be great.

Comment: What scope is `child1` in? Unless they're global, this won't work.

Comment: Sounds like your script is being called before the DOM is finished loading. Try moving your `<script>` call just before `</body>` if you havent' already done so.

Comment: @Andy Probably not the case, getting `innerHTML` of `undefined` would trigger an error.

Comment: Well, it will give `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined` on loading, and if the OP tried logging `arr`, it would also give `undefined`, so I think that's close. The OP might be paraphrasing what he sees. Best eliminating the most obvious error first before moving on to something less obvious in my experience.

Comment: @Andy Well, maybe you're right, only that OP didn't mention about error at all ...

Comment: Needs more [mcve].

Comment: @Carcigenicate The variables is in Global Scope. They are directly in the <script></script> tag and not nested.

Comment: @Andy Looks like your solution is working, but when I did it I got another problem in the code, I'll try expeiment with the code and will comment again.

Thanks All :))

Comment: @Andy , Your solution is completely worked, I don't know why I couldn't accept your answer as best answer, so I let you all know here. Thanks :)